# Cannot see UILabel in a UICollectionViewCell added programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I create a UICollectionViewCell programmatically when the user start a PanGesture on my CollectionView to reorder the cells (I don't use Apple APIs because I have to personalise the behaviour).

I create a Cell from a custom class `WordCollectionViewCell` that has an IBOutlet. Here is the code of the class:

```
class WordCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!
}
```

To create the cell and add it to the CollectionView I use this code:

```
    self.movingCell = {
        let mC = WordCollectionViewCell(frame: selectedCell.frame)

        // I HAVE TO DO THIS WITH A VARIABLE BECAUSE IF I ASSIGN UILabel() DIRECTLY TO mC.wordlabel, THE APP CRASH BECAUSE wordLabel IS NIL
        let label = UILabel()
        mC.wordLabel = label


        mC.wordLabel.text = selectedCell.wordLabel.text
        mC.addSubview(mC.wordLabel)

        mC.backgroundColor = selectedCell.backgroundColor
        mC.layer.cornerRadius = selectedCell.layer.cornerRadius
        mC.tag = selectedIndexPath.row
        return mC
    }()

    self.collectionView.addSubview(self.movingCell)

    self.collectionView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: movingCell.wordLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: movingCell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.collectionView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: movingCell.wordLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: movingCell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.collectionView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: movingCell.wordLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: movingCell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.collectionView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: movingCell.wordLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: movingCell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

The Cell will follow the PanGesture location.

With this code there are two problems:

1. I see nothing in `movingCell` testing on my device;
2. Why I have can't set `UILabel()` directly to `wordLabel`?

Comment: Sorry if I've made some mistakes with the language, I'm italian

Comment: Hi there. I have a question for you. You label is IBOutlet, but you add it programmatically. What is the reason?

Comment: @iWheelBuy I use the IBOutlet because I load the Collection View Controller from the Storyboard and in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`  I set the text of every cell, but now I need to create it programmatically

Comment: And do you have WordCollectionViewCell in interface builder?

Comment: @iWheelBuy Yes, I have

Comment: It looks like you initialize you cell not from interface builder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125731/discussion-between-iwheelbuy-and-ale00).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`